# d3.js force cancel a drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js

I have a simple drag event - and if a certain condition is met, I'd like to force cancel the drag currently under way (basically as if you were doing a mouseup).

Something like so:

```
var drag_behavior = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function() {
    if(mycondition){
       // cancel the drag event
    }
});
```

EDIT:

the goal is simply to prevent people from dragging a world map outside certain boundaries in such a way that renders the map in mid-ocean (details below).

Current map code:

```
var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height/1.5])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var drag_behavior_map = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function() {
    drag_click = true //used later to prevent dragend to fire off a click event
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    // original idea
    // if(worldmap_left_boundary > 0 || worldmap_right_boundary < screen.height){
    //    cancel or limit the drag here
    // }
});

var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
.call(drag_behavior_map)
```

[image: This should not be possible]

Basically this should not be possible.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "cancel the drag event" -- you can always just choose to return from the event listener method without making any changes.  Or you can add conditions to the changes you make, as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377) which bounds how far a node can be dragged by applying a max/min function.

Comment: How did things work out for you?

Comment: hey @meetamit actually not that good. I don't think "canceling" the drag event is going to work, I haven't seen anyone doing it this way. It doesn't seem to be possible to interrupt a drag progammatically, at least I tried your 2 suggestions + variants and it did not fire at all. the suggestion from AmeliaBR might be better suited, although I haven't been able to find code references for this. I have a simple world map that's draggable/zoomable, but I don't want people to drag the map outside of the limits of its projection! I'll update with some code in my original question.

Comment: Constraining the panning is similar to the link @AmeliaBR provided, but in your case you'd constrain the geo projection's rotation rather than the x and y coordinates, still using `Math.min` and `Math.max`. For more specific help, you should show the code you wrote for dragging the map –– inside `.on("drag", function() {});` –– even if it doesn't yet account for limiting the dragging.

Comment: I added my original intent (+ the little code that is kind of unrelated), but never got this to work, so there isn't anything there for the moment :)

Comment: Check out [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jczaplew/6457917) to see how to rotate the projection on drag. The projection is different than the one you're using, but same formula should work.

Comment: You're absolutely correct - I think this is more a problem of me not knowing I needed a rotation. Your link uses a different projection than mine so the calculations are a bit off, but I can patch it with http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6621971 and I'm all good to go. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the `drag` event function, you can use `mycondition` to decide whether or not to update the dragged element's position. Not updating the position essentially means stopping the drag.

You could also unsubscribe from the `drag` event:

```
var drag_behavior = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", function() {
    if(mycondition) {
       // cancel the drag event
       drag_behavior.on("drag", null);
    }
  });
```

Note, there would still be a `dragend` event, unless you unsubscribe that one too.

Alternatively –– though I'm not totally familiar with triggering native events and how that affects `d3.behavior.drag()` –– you can try triggering a native `mouseup` event and see what happens.

```
var drag_behavior = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", function() {
    if(mycondition) {
      // "this" is the dragged dom element
      this.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseup'))
    }
  });
```

Comment: Dispatching the mouseup event is a nice idea, but didn't work for me.